# Why is c++ telling me that no [] matches the type I pass in?

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
static const map<const Type*, int>* priority;
```

where Type is my own special class.

Initialization (why c++ demanded this I have no idea, auto wouldn't even work)

```
const map<const Type*, int, less<const Type*>, allocator<pair<const Type* const, int>>>* ToolProperty::priority
= new map<const Type*, int, less<const Type*>, allocator<pair<const Type* const, int>>>();
```

And finally, trying to use it (where it is telling me that I'm passing in the wrong type)

```
static void setPriority(const Type* type, int newPriority)
{
    (*priority)[type] = newPriority;
}
```

Comment: C++ is a programming language, it doesn't tell you things. What is your compiler saying? (as in, what compiler are you using and what is the error or warning that you are getting?)

Comment: Why are you using so many pointers? That seems like a bit of a code smell.

Comment: There's no reason to spell out the comparator and the allocator if all you want is the default. Just leave them out.

Comment: Oh, but when I left them out, it threw syntax errors at me :p. This is why I said "I don't know why it's demanding this of me" and why I also said "auto wouldn't even work" : P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

priority is a pointer to a const map, but operator[] can't be used with `const associative containers`.

Comment: @user1136671 operator[] can't be used with const, because it actually inserts a new element into the map if it's argument is not already in the map.